# using ref.current as container in react portal throws Target container is not a DOM element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

I am using react portal to render inside dom element rendered by parent element

```
import { useRef, useState } from "react";
import { createPortal } from "react-dom";

export default function App() {
  const pageTitleRef = useRef(null);
  const [page, setPage] = useState(true);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header>
        <h1>
          App-<span id="page-title" ref={pageTitleRef}></span>
        </h1>
        <button
          onClick={(e) => {
            setPage((p) => !p);
          }}
        >
          toggle page
        </button>
      </header>
      {page ? (
        <Page1 key="page1" pageTitleRef={pageTitleRef} />
      ) : (
        <Page2 key="page2" pageTitleRef={pageTitleRef} />
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

function Page1({ pageTitleRef }) {
  return (
    <div className="Page1">
      {createPortal("Page2 title", pageTitleRef.current)}
      <h2>Page 1 content!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

function Page2({ pageTitleRef }) {
  return (
    <div className="Page2">
      {createPortal("Page1 title", pageTitleRef.current)}
      <h2>Page 2 content!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

however it throws an error `Target container is not a DOM element.`

https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-mendeleev-b5pbr?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're trying to use `pageTitleRef.current` before it has anything in it. It doesn't have anything in it until `App` renders, but *during* the rendering of `App`, you're trying to call `createPortal` (from `Page1` and `Page2`).

You'll need to do some refactoring; some options:

1. Render normally in that area, rather than having `Page1` and `Page2` reach out to it via `createPortal`; `App` already knows what page it's on.
2. Put the portal area in your skeleton HTML, rather than rendering it with `App`.
3. Hold the content that should be in the header in `App` state and pass a setter function to `Page1` and `Page2` they can use to set that content.

I'd go with #1, `Page1` and `Page2` seem to have too many responsibilities (page header and page body). You could split them up into `PageHead1`/`PageHead2` and `PageBody1`/`PageBody2`. But if it makes more sense, either #2 or #3 could work too.